# How to install JHawk(plugin) into Eclipse

Tags: java, plugins, installation, eclipse-plugin

I need to install JHawk onto my pc so that it works with eclipse. But there does not seem to be a clear way for me to install it. I have no experience in installing plugins to eclipse and I am wondering what im missing.[image: Folder of JHawk]

Comment: Does copying the `JHawkDemo_6.1.0.jar` file into the `dropins` folder of your Eclipse installation work?

Answer (score 0):

This is what it says in a PDF file found in that Docs directory you have there:

> After you have unzipped the JHawk Distribution into a directory you
>   will find a sub-folder named „plugins‟. Close down your Eclipse
>   application if it is already running. Copy the jar in the plugins
>   directory into the plugins directory of your eclipse folder. Copy the
>   jhawk.properties file in the plugins directory to the root directory
>   of your Eclipse installation (this is the directory where you find
>   eclipse.exe). When you restart Eclipse JHawk will be ready for use.
>   The Eclipse plugin has been tested used in Eclipse 4.4 (Luna), 4.5
>   (Mars) and 4.6 (Neon) and will probably work in other versions.     As
>   part of the distribution you will notice the following properties
>   files –
>
> - jhawkbase.properties
> - jhawkfull.properties
> - jhawkbasepluscustom.properties
> - reviewfactor.properties
>
>   jhawkbase.properties is a version of the properties file with the
>     base level set of  metrics that are initially enabled for JHawk. This
>     is the same as the jhawk.properties file that comes with the JHawk
>     Eclipse plugin distribution.    jhawkfull.properties is a version of
>     the properties file with the full set of  metrics available to JHawk 
>     enabled.     jhawkbasepluscustom.properties is a version of the
>     properties file with the base level set of  metrics that are initially
>     enabled for JHawk plus the sample metric found in the
>     CustomMetrics.jar that comes with the distribution. For more details
>     about this metric see the „JHawk5CreateMetric‟ document.    You can
>     use any of these sets of metrics by copying them to the
>     jhawk.properties file and starting as normal or by using the –p flag
>     and the property file name (JHawk Command Line only).    Properties
>     loaded from these files can be amended in the usual way – see
>     „Preferences‟ section in the documentation.
>     reviewfactor.properties – this file contains properties used by the
>     class and package Review Factor metrics. You can find out more about
>     how to use these properties in the „Using the Review Factor Metric‟
>     section of the JHawk6UsingMetrics document supplied with the
>     distribution.

If you actually open the JHawkDemo_6.1.0.jar archive, inside, you'll find JHawkDemo.jar, which seems to be the actual plugin archive. The instructions seem to suggest that you drop that into the plugins folder located immediately within your Eclipse workspace directory. Then launch Eclipse and you should see it work.

Having done exactly that, however, I can see no sign of JHawk within Eclipse (2019-9). Moving the archive to the dropins folder also yields nothing. Help > About Eclipse IDE > Installed Software is supposed to list all the plugins installed, and there's no JHawk. There are no JHawk tabs as indicated, and Help > Preferences shows no sign of JHawk.

The latest version of JHawk is three years out of date, and the doc doesn't seem to correspond well to what's actually on offer. I can't get this plugin to install, but I thought I'd leave this blob of information for the sake of posterity so that I won't feel like I spent 30 min and accomplished nothing.

Comment: Putting things directly in the plugins directory hasn't been supported by Eclipse for quite a while. Sometimes starting Eclipse with the -clean option will get this to work.

Comment: @greg-449 Yeah. JHawk sounds a bit like a bedroom software company. The site isn't well updated, the docs aren't well maintained... I wouldn't doubt that the software is also out of date and doesn't account for the latest Eclipse architecture.